# Find JIRA issues that have not been updated

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a way to find, via the integrated search, JIRA issues that have not been updated for more than a certain number of days... in order to solve/delete them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JQL can you try to use a filter like this :

> updated > "-1d"

for tickets updated last day ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQL as described by @Guillaume
however if you want to solve them and then delete them, usually it is best to run a bulk update and add a tag, because after the first bulk update to solve them the JQL will not be valid anymore.
This is assuming that you want to solve first and then delete obviously